# Bookmarklet for posting to my site: use IFrame or separate browser window

Tags: user-interface, bookmarklet

In a site I'm working on, songfountain.com, we have a bookmarklet.

songfountain is like delicious and twitter, except it's specifically for song links.

The songfountain bookmarklet functions similarly to the delicious and twitter bookmarklets. It grabs the URL and copies it in to a form field; the form has a button, and submits to songfountain.com -> simple social bookmarking.

Google Notebook (when it was still available) also had a bookmarlet. Google Notebook's and songfountain's bookmarklet open the form within an IFRAME within the current page.

Delicious and twitter open a new browser window.

Opening a new browser window looks more robust, but I myself don't like windows opened for "small stuff" like this. I don't know if I'm overlooking some technical problem that I haven't run into yet.

Question: Is it better to use an IFRAME? Or is it better to open a new browser window?

Answer (score 2):

From a user/usability perspective, an IFrame is, generally, less disruptive and more user friendly. It also doesn't run into problems with pop-up and ad-blockers on the users' machine.

Look at the "Note in reader" bookmarklet that is provided to Google Reader users for inspiration. There may be other tricks you could consider, besides IFrame and pop-up.

Comment: Thanks. That's good. I didn't know Google Reader had that as well. When you mention "Look at ... Google Reader ... for inspiration", do you mean the selected-text-gets-copied-to-the-note feature combined with the "Refresh" link? -- Stephan

Comment: Oh ok. I found the "auto-populate" a bit tricky to implement, but its covered.I find the Refresh link a bit confusing. Once you have selected the text it looks easy and obvious enough to copy it into the field by yourself -- instead of clicking a link (which should be a button?!)